# Managing IObservable dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, architecture, system.reactive

I have an parameterized Observable that I create using a factory, i.e.

```
// tick when the day changes in a given timezone
IObservable<DateTime> GetInstrumentTzDateRollObservable(string timeZoneName)
```

Under the hood it uses Observable.Timer so there is a cost involved that means I'd not want to create too many of these (the example is simplified, the real life one has much higher cost per observable).

Now, if there is only one consumer everything is simple - we just continue building the pipeline. But the subscribers are dynamic, i.e. the user can open a new screen that will need the same data. It seems what I need is a way to cache observables per timezone so that a consumer would get a stream from this cache if present (GetOrAdd). The simple solution is of course a class that holds a dictionary of these observables.

My question is isn't there a better way to share these intermediate streams by registering them with special DI container or similar which would in essence provide the same functionality as the cache described above. I read enough about service locator anti-pattern and not using DI for anything but instantiation so it seems it is not recommended. Nevertheless I don't really see what my own class would do much differently from a DI container.

**Update**: as requested, I want to provide a more realistic scenario of a perceived high cost of generating elements of an observable. I hope this one is clearer.

There is a database that holds data for all instruments. There is a loader that can retrieve data per instrument. There is a notification stream that ticks when the data was updated. The loader also needs the date to prepare the loaded data. The result is then presented as an observable stream:

```
    IObservable<IntrumentData> GetExpensiveDbDataStreamPerIntrument(string instrumentName)
    {
        // date provider ticks when a day in a given timezone changes prompting us to reload from source
        _dateProvider.GetInstrumentTzDateRollObservable(instrumentName)
            // combine with new data notifications to force a reload
            .CombineLatest(_newDataNotificationObservable.GetNotificationsForInstrument(instrumentName), (date, event) => date)
            .Select(date => _dataLoader.LoadData(instrumentName, date))
            // this has been expensive to load so we want to be able to share the result
            .Replay(1).RefCount();
    }
```

So - how can I share these expensive streams when the client can subscribe and unsubscribe dynamically selecting instruments from a long list and using multiple screens that would need the same instrument data?

Comment: "Under the hood it uses Observable.Timer so there is a cost involved that means I'd not want to create too many of these" - is there a performance and/or cost issue here? Have you measured it? Rx has been written to reuse resources like timers.

Comment: The only way that I can recommend any approach to cache observables is to see a [mcve] of a basic, measurable, uncached implementation. Then I could implement a cache and see the measured differences. Right now you've only shown us a basic signature that really doesn't give us any idea if there is a problem or if an alternative is solving that potential problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Enigmativity. I was afraid the measuring would come into play here hence made a note about the real-life case being different. I will update the question.